# To automatically insert value from SEQUENCE without using trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE A
    MINVALUE 1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

I want to create a table :

```
 CREATE TABLE t1(
 id NUMBER NUMBER DEFAULT A.NEXTVAL,
 description varchar(20))
```

Such that whenever I insert, the id column is automatically populated without using trigger. 
 
I tried inserting :`INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('hello')` 
Error :`ORA-00947: not enough values`

Comment: Are you sure you're on 11g? The `create table` should have errored if so. Well, firstly because you have `NUMBER` twice; but without that typo, with "ORA-00984: column not allowed here". If the table was created with the sequence in it, then what does `select * from v$version` tell you the version number is? Either way, the actual error you reported is from not supplying the column name, as Tejash said.

Comment: So this I tried on higher version,  just to check if it works. I was asking if there is any way like this in 11g without the use of trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORA-00947: not enough values` --> It simply means that you have not provided the column list in `INSERT` and you are trying to insert fewer values than total number of columns in your table. You should provide the name of the column.

It is possible in Oracle 12c. You just have to provide a column list (excluding the default column) as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE A MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE T1 (
  2  ID            NUMBER DEFAULT A.NEXTVAL,
  3  DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR(20)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO T1 ( DESCRIPTION ) VALUES ( 'd1' );

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO T1 ( DESCRIPTION ) VALUES ( 'd2' );

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM T1;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------
         1 d1
         2 d2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you can't, not in Oracle 11g.

If you were on 12c, you could use an identity column, but - you are not.

Therefore, trigger it is (unless you want to specify the sequence each time you insert rows into the table).

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Oracle 12c, the only way to do that is using a trigger. In Oracle 12c there are IDENTITY columns

columns were introduced in Oracle 12c, allowing for simple auto increment functionality in modern versions of Oracle.

Using the IDENTITY column is functionally similar to that of other database systems. In Oracle 12c or higher, we could use identity columns to reference sequence or incremental values. You can see in the link below examples of how to use IDENTITY, but in Oracle 11g the only mode is using triggers.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1